How to set proxy credentials with NEPacketTunnelProvider and NEProxySettings?
In an iOS app (react native) I am creating a fake vpn connection with NEPacketTunnelProvider and configuring a proxy. auth is required for the proxy I am using.
override func startTunnel(options: [String : NSObject]?, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    
    let settings = NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings(tunnelRemoteAddress: "10.0.0.1")
    let proxySettings = NEProxySettings()

    proxySettings.autoProxyConfigurationEnabled = true
    proxySettings.httpEnabled = true
    proxySettings.httpsEnabled = true
    proxySettings.excludeSimpleHostnames = false 
    proxySettings.matchDomains = [""]
    proxySettings.exceptionList = ["192.168.0.0/16".....]
    
    let httpServer = NEProxyServer(address: HOST_IP1, port: PORT1)
    let httpsServer = NEProxyServer(address: HOST_IP2, port: PORT2)
   
    httpServer.username = "xxx"
    httpServer.password = "yyy"
    
    httpsServer.username = "xxx"
    httpsServer.password = "yyy"
    httpServer.authenticationRequired = true
    httpsServer.authenticationRequired = true
  
    proxySettings.httpServer = httpServer
    proxySettings.httpsServer = httpsServer
    
    settings.proxySettings = proxySettings
    settings.mtu = 1400
    
     setTunnelNetworkSettings(settings) { error in
      ....
     }
    }

I think I have done all the settings. but it tells me auth required (http) when logging in to sites or sometimes immediately after connecting, sometimes with an alert. on some sites I get invalid auth credentials.
I don't want to have to use pac.
I don't need to make these settings in let tunnelProtocol = NETunnelProviderProtocol(), right?
Thank you for the explanatory answers, I must solve this problem.

What software layer is providing the proxy re-direction? it is probably also providing the interactive prompt for proxy auth (even if it is mislabeled). (I'm assuming this is the Apple-provided framework)

I am only using PacketTunnel with network extension. I tried to create a proxy over vpn connection. @benc
